# Exception using AsynchronousSocketChannel, ByteBuffer and Future

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, asynchronous

There is a task: to make a multi-threaded execution of functions using      `AsynchronousSocketChannel`. To simulate long work on the server side i'm using `Thread.sleep()` (stored in the class `Worker`). If I `sleep()` threads for more than 2 seconds, when obtaining data on the client side using `ByteBuffer` and `Future`, flies `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` (my function `printFuncResult`) Tell me, please, what's the problem?

Server:

```
public class Server {
public static final InetSocketAddress hostAddress = new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 5678);

private AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel;
private AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel;
ExecutorService threadPool;

public Server() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    serverChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open();
    serverChannel.bind(hostAddress);
    System.out.println("Server channel bound to port: " + hostAddress.getPort());
    System.out.println("Waiting for client to connect... ");
    getClientChannel();
    handleArguments();
}

private void getClientChannel() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Future<AsynchronousSocketChannel> acceptResult = serverChannel.accept();
    clientChannel = acceptResult.get();
}

private void handleArguments() throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    if ((clientChannel != null) && (clientChannel.isOpen())) {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
        Future<Integer> result = clientChannel.read(buffer);
        while (! result.isDone()) {
          //  System.out.println("Result coming... ");
        }
        buffer.flip();
        int x = buffer.getInt(0);

        Worker workerOne = new Worker(Worker.TYPE_F, x, clientChannel);
        Worker workerTwo = new Worker(Worker.TYPE_G, x, clientChannel);

        threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        threadPool.execute(workerOne);
        threadPool.execute(workerTwo);


        Thread.sleep(3000);
        clientChannel.close();
    }
}
}

class Worker implements Runnable {
public static final int TYPE_F = 1;
public static final int TYPE_G = 2;
private int x;
private int type;
private AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel;

public Worker(int type, int x, AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel) {
    this.x = x;
    this.type = type;
    this.clientChannel = clientChannel;
}

private void sendResultToClient(int res) {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    if (type == TYPE_F) {
        res = 4545;
    } else {
        res = 34234;
    }
    buffer.putInt(0, type);
    buffer.putInt(4, res);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10000; ++j) {
            int k = i*j + i/(j +1) + i + j + Math.max(i, j);
        }
    }
    boolean written = false;
    while (!written) {
        try {
            clientChannel.write(buffer);
            written = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    int result = -1;
    Random random = new Random();
    switch (type) {
        case TYPE_F :
            result = (int)Math.pow(x, x);
            break;
        case TYPE_G :
            result = (int)Math.pow(x, x / 2);
            break;
    }
    sendResultToClient(result);
}
}
```

Client:

```
public class Client {
private AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel;
ExecutorService threadPool;

public Client(int x) throws IOException, InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    threadPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
    boolean connected = false;
    while (!connected) {
        try {
            clientChannel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
            Future<Void> future = clientChannel.connect(Server.hostAddress);
            future.get();
            connected = true;
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {}
    }
    System.out.println("Client is started: " + clientChannel.isOpen());
    System.out.println("Sending messages to server: ");
    sendArguments(x);
    //showCancelDialog();
    listenResult();
    clientChannel.close();
}



private void sendArguments(int x) throws InterruptedException, IOException {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    buffer.putInt(0, x);
    Future<Integer> result = clientChannel.write(buffer);
    while (! result.isDone()) {
        System.out.println("... ");
    }
}

private boolean waitForResult(Future <Pair <Integer, Integer>> futureResult) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (!futureResult.isDone() ) {
        System.out.println("DOING.. break? (y/n)");
        String input = sc.next();
        if (input.equals("y")) {
            System.out.println("CANCELLED");
            threadPool.shutdownNow();
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

private void printFuncResult(Future <Pair <Integer, Integer>> futureResult) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Integer funcType = new Integer(futureResult.get().getKey());
    Integer result = new Integer(futureResult.get().getValue());

    System.out.println("RESULT OF "+ funcType +" FUNC = " + result);
}

private void listenResult() throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {

    System.out.println("Wating for result...");

    Listener listener = new Listener(clientChannel);

    Future <Pair <Integer, Integer>> futureResult = threadPool.submit(listener);
    if (!waitForResult(futureResult)) {
        return;
    }

    printFuncResult(futureResult);

    futureResult = threadPool.submit(listener);

    if (!waitForResult(futureResult)) {
        return;
    }

    printFuncResult(futureResult);

}
}

class Listener implements Callable <Pair <Integer, Integer>> {
private AsynchronousSocketChannel clientChannel;

public Listener(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel) {
    this.clientChannel = channel;
}

@Override
public Pair <Integer, Integer> call() throws Exception {
    ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(32);
    Future<Integer> futureResult = clientChannel.read(buffer);
    while (! futureResult.isDone()) {}
    buffer.flip();
    Integer type = new Integer(buffer.getInt(0));
    Integer result = new Integer (buffer.getInt(4));
    return new Pair<Integer, Integer>(type, result);
}
}
}
```

Comment: @willshackleford bytes_read = -1 and if retry -1 too. So it doesnt help. I think the problem in clientChannel.write() on server.

Comment: Stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

The IndexOutOfBoundsException is not coming from printFuncResult. It is only stored in the future  and printed with the stack trace there. The IndexOutOfBoundsException is generated in Listener call function  on this line:

```
Integer type = new Integer(buffer.getInt(0));
```

This will happen if the read did not read a sufficient number of bytes.

I suggest you replace this inefficient and hard to debug while loop .

```
while (! futureResult.isDone()) {}
```

with something like

```
int bytes_read = futureResult.get();
if(bytes_read != 32) {
   // log error or throw exception or retry ...
}
```